# Request callback with node

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to create a callback function, but keep getting told that `data is not a function`. I've set it up according to another question, but does not seem to work?

```
getRequest("http://", function(error, data){
  console.log(data);
});

function getRequest(url, error, data) {
  request({
      method: 'GET',
      uri: url,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'dataType': 'json'}
    }, function (error, response, body){
      if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){

        data(JSON.parse(body));

      } else {
        error(error);
      }
    })
}
```

Comment: You are calling `getRequest` with two params. so the third `data` param is `undefined`.

Comment: i see, but how should it then look like in this case?

Comment: You might want to consider using a promise library like [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com) to keep your callbacks under control. Chaining `then(...)` is often a lot easier than matching up function calls.

Answer (score 1):

In case if you want to proceed both, success and failure result in one callback you should replace calling `data` with `cb`(or `error` as was in your code.

```
getRequest("http://", function(error, data){
  if(error) throw error
  console.log(data)
});

function getRequest(url, cb, data) {
  request({
      method: 'GET',
      uri: url,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'dataType': 'json'}
    }, function (error, response, body){
      if(cb) {
          cb(error, JSON.parse(body))
      }
    })
}
```

Otherwise, you should check if both callbacks provided

```
function getRequest(url, success, error) {
  request({
      method: 'GET',
      uri: url,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'dataType': 'json'}
    }, function (error, response, body){
      if(error && failure) {
         failure(error)
      } else if(success) {
         success(JSON.parse(body))
      }
    })
}
```

In this case, you should provide two callback functions, first for success result and a second one for error which is less common pattern.

Comment: Using a single callback of the form `function(error, body)` is more consistent here.

Comment: @tadman, you're absolutely right, I've added a remark about that but I'm not sure if it fits OP needs so just in case provided another option.

Comment: Node.js is pretty adamant about keeping things consistent that way and while I thought it was strange when I started with it, that habit does keep your code a lot more orderly. The wild-west approach from before with dozens of contradictory callback methods is fading into history.